# Save Archive Data (BLOB) to MS Azure

Tags: azure, archive

my Company is considering MS Azure as archive for some compliance reasons.
I'll make it short: the tool is saving pdf(a) files and can only save them through a path of the local file System.
Is it possible to save on azure through a local file path?
I can't find anything on the Portal and I can't create Import Jobs just with the Portal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your company doesn't block port 445 you can create an azure file share as part of the Azure Storage service.  You are able to map a drive to your local machine and drag and drop as needed.